# Bundling in visual studio 2012

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

On final stage of bundling my files, on a View page i have this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

if look in browser f12 - i see this

```
<link href="/bundles/app?v=msuiGrpPHwW0spb2jAusEby6pbx1AF86dWvqCB0GeVU1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

but it says "404 Not Found"
in other hand , if i go `localhost:8384/bundles/app?v=msuiGrpPHwW0spb2jAusEby6pbx1AF86dWvqCB0GeVU1`
i see well-optimized css file which i actually wanted. Why is this happening and how do i use this file in my css\html?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If the URL works when visiting directly, you should not get a 404 when linking it in a html file.

Comment: are you sure `404 Not Found` does not relate to a different link?

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, yes i am sure
if i copy link from error console to a adress line and press enter i open css minified file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , problem was with extension : i had to add extension .css to file when creating bundle and on Render moment

app.css